# does glassfish support password aliases in jvm args?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

I'm trying to use an aliased password as a jvm arg, but the aliased password does not seem to be provided to the web app.  Here is my domain.xml config:

```
<jvm-options>-Dmy_password=${ALIAS=my_password_alias}</jvm-options>
```

However, trying to retrieve the password just returns null

```
String password = System.getEnv("my_password"); // returns null
```

and

```
String password = System.getProperty("my_password"); // returns "${ALIAS=my_password_alias}"
```

I've tried on: **GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)**

Searching online it seems someone else has run into a [similar issue](https://www.java.net//node/697340)

**Question:** does glassfish support password aliases for jvm args?

Comment: Please note the comment from @MarcosZolnowski below. This is a bug (**[GLASSFISH-18961](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18961)** ) which has been fixed in GF v.  4.0_b50_ms4

Comment: Here is the fix : https://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/revision/55379

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, just use `System.getProperty("my_password")`.

Comment: Have you tried this Marcos?  It didn't work for me on 3.1.2.2.

Comment: Tried on GlassFish 4.0

Comment: Would you know of an official bug report which proves that this is indeed a bug in GF 3.xx ?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal Probably [GLASSFISH-18961](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18961).