# Adding SSL keystore password as alias in domain.xml

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, jvm, glassfish-3

I'm trying to add the keystore and truststore passwords in the domain.xml for glassfish 3.1.2.2 as jvm options.

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${ALIAS=keystorepassword}
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${ALIAS=truststorepassword}

Using aliases seems to not be working.

Any ideas how this can achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers who reach this question, hoping to do this for Glassfish 3.1.2.x, this is not possible due to the bug [**GLASSFISH-18961**](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18961) :

[image]

The bug has been fixed. The fix referenced in the above ticket is here : https://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/revision/55379, but it has not been backported to Glassfish 3.x

Also, according to this questions "[does glassfish support password aliases in jvm args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189249/does-glassfish-support-password-aliases-in-jvm-args)", this works fine in Glassfish 4.